# Посилання на англ-рос-англ словники, а також на решту словників з перекладом не на українську

Tags: discussion, resources

https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2909/240

У цій відповіді @Artemix посилається на словник мультитран, що перекладає поміж англійською і російською мовами.

Як мені перевіряти джерела і дивитися, що там написано, якщо я не розумію російської?

Всі ми знаємо, що такі люди існують і на українотеренних землях, і у Канаді, наприклад, у США, багато де. Як їм працювати з такими джерелами? Чому немає посилань на словенські, польські словники, але з’являються посилання на російські словники?

Поясніть, будь ласка.

Особиста позиція моя така, що немає тут бути таких джерел, зрозуміло.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73624/discussion-on-question-by-p-vovk---------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У правилах сайту нема вимог що посилання повинні бути тільки на україномовні джерела. Сайт дозволяє писати пости (відповіді і питання) двома мовами - українською та англійською. У питанні автор зазначає, що українські словники не дали йому потрібних за контекстом значень - варіанти "партизан" і "партійний" йому не підійшли.

Чому для розширення контексту не можна користуватися іншомовними джерелами? Я згоден що відповідь може посилатися на чеські, польські, словенські сайти і насправді у нас на Ukrainian.SE є відповіді з подібними посиланнями. Я користувався іншомовними джерелами для розширення контексту тлумачення **англійського** слова. Наскільки мені відомо у перекладацькій практиці трапляються випадки коли для перекладу слова доводиться користуватися проміжними мовами (наприклад з німецької на англійську а потім з англійської на українську), тому не бачу у такому залученні ніякого порушення логіки чи здорового глузду.

Звичайно, посилання на прямий англо-український словник буде якісно кращим, але я поки що не бачу спроб зробити конструктивних кроків щодо покращення існуючої  або надання більш якісної відповіді.

Comment: Проміжними мовами треба користуватися обережно. Тому що у тайській «партія» у значенні faction — це ฝ่าย, походить від слова «бавовна/вата». І це значення має глибоке історичне підґрунтя, ще з часів, коли протоукраїнці говорили санскритом. :-)

Comment: @bytebuster Тайська мова все ж дальша від української, ніж російська.

Comment: дуже дякую вам за нормальну реакцію. я згодний, що іноді можна користуватися, але мультитран - точно не найкраще джерело інформації. там багато помилок. колись давно натрапляв на купу, тож припинив користуватися. 
також дякую вам за те, що знайшли час на редаґування своєї відповіді.
і останнє: "Запропонуйте якісні англо-українські словники і я буду користуватися ними." оце наша проблема. всі хочуть, щоб їм все дали. я стараюся, звісно, давати, але не всесильний. але закцентуватися треба на створенні, але на вимаганні чогось від інших. розумію, що це не до вас закид, але зовсім трохи і до вас

Comment: @P.Vovk Мультитран не можна використовувати в тому сенсі, що "якщо там щось є, то так можна і правильно", бо там справді багато помилок (до деяких з них є коменти у дужках, до деяких немає). Але він буває корисний в тому аспекті, що там можна знайти якийсь конкретний переклад, який годиться у зараз мною оброблюваному випадку. Сміття можна і треба ігнорувати. Але це не означає, що там все треба відкидати.

Answer (score 1):

Схоже, пан [P. Vovk](/users/240/) намагався бути дуже обережним, тому вся суть теми не передалася темнішим. Промах. Дійсно, тема вельми делікатненька, тому спробую пояснити і задати напрям, аби ця делікатність не заважала.

**Суть**, наскільки я зрозумів, саме така: **Московщина**! Не треʼ боятися цӧго слова, бо, пан так перевертає карту, а не як вельмичутливий пан [tenebris2020](/users/1439/tenebris2020) — провокує чи вказує инших і закриває тему.

А яка саме тут «московщина»? Заохочений українець би поцікавився: сусідніми, иншими словʼянськими чи ключнопроміжними (німецька чи французька) мовами, а не тільки, як «пересічному» українцю зі своєю звичкою чи лінню, до імперської московскої мови, яка, все ж таки без сумніву (і трохи жалю), теж є ключовою і проміжною. Але через ту недбалість, знов триваʼ несвідома залежність від московської мови навіть у незалежні часи.

Свідомі українці і несвідомий я розуміють, так не можна, треʼ щось робить. Тому очевидне питання тут зовсім инше: **ми не знаємо инші словники чи не можемо їх відшукати**.

Про погані наслідки від чищення мови чи уникнень прямих запозичень — доволі гучна і необґрунтова заява, тим паче існує деякий приклад-заперечення у [вигляді ісляндської мови](//r2u.org.ua/node/45).

Тому на таку суть треʼ **відповідати словниками**. Пізніше обробити у зручну збірку на штиб [Корисні ланки](/questions/8).

---

**Отже!**

Один з найкращих словників на базисі німецького — [dict](//dict.cc). Чудовий також тим, що включає чи посилає на ті самі инші словники, причому кількість, як на мене, відносно вражаюча. А [**тут**](//contribute.dict.cc/?action=lang-wishlist) можете пропрохати українську мову чи запропонувати себе у якости учасника:

*#24  Ukrainian

89 possible future contributor(s)

294 total request(s)*

Тепер приклад:

＞ https://enpl.dict.cc/?s=partisan

partyzancki
*woj.* partyzant
*woj.* partyzantka]

*На цӧму можна не зупинятися, унизу ланки на инші словники чи просто ӝерела:*

Google – Wikipedia – Wiktionary – dict.pl – PONS – Onet – Interia – Pittsburgh

Деякі працюють цілком і корисні.

＞ http://tlumacz.interia.pl/szukaj?q=partisan

**partisan**
stronnik; zwolennik; poplecznik; partyzant; adherent

**non-partisan**
bezpartyjny

＞ http://edict.pl/dict?word=partisan

**partisan**
partyzant; stronnik; zwolennik

**nonpartisan**
bezpartyjny; niezaangażowany

**bipartisan**
ponadpartyjny; ponad podziałami

*Лятинські букви читать уміємо, але можливі проблеми:*

- Чи справді так звучить?
- Що то слово означаʼ, наприклад **zwolennik**, але детальніше?

Перше питання легко вирішується звичаєвим пошуком і не завше обовʼязкове для відповіді тут.

А для другого треʼ вже постаратися, але для сусідних мов, як от польською, можуть урятувати тлумачники.

Мені відомі такі:

＞ https://sjp.pl/zwolennik

osoba popierająca coś lub kogoś; stronnik

＞ http://wsjp.pl/index.php?id_hasla=4042
＞＞ POKAŻ WSZYSTKO
＞＞＞ http://wsjp.pl/do_druku.php?id_hasla=4042

*Вельми широка сторінка і можна взнати нового.*

Od st.pol. *zwolić* 'wyratować, ocalić; wyrazić zgodę, przystać na coś', z czeskiego 'wybrać, przeznaczyć na coś'. Kontynuuje *psł.* *sъ-voliti 'wyrazić swą wolę, pozwolić, zezwolić'

1. osoba, które popiera jakąś osobę
2. osoba, która jest przekonana o słuszności jakiejś idei, koncepcji lub jakiegoś działania i często je aktywnie popiera

*Також не слід забувати про синоніми, навіть тут польська включила з анґлійської [adherent](//dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adherent).*

Коли знов пошукати по знаӧмому:

＞ https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=adherent

*Видно, що переважно прикріплюється закінченнями. Наприклад, республіканець, маккейнівець тощо. Але для окремого слова знаходимо таке:*

**сторо́нник (-ка)**
partisan, adherent, partyman, supporter

**односу́м (-ма)**
comrade, political friend (adherent); fellow-inmate; accomplice;

Comment: Ваша відповідь якраз іде всупереч тому, що написав П.Вовк. Він хоче заборонити словники з третіх мов. Той факт, що ви, схоже, відчуваєте себе на його боці, але одночасно робите якраз так, як він хоче заборонити, явна ознака того, що тут десь не спрацювала логіка. (Не кажучи вже про те, що перекласти іменник partisan – для якого вже є слово "прибічник", тому запозичень не потрібно – не означає перекласти те значення _прикметника_  partisan, яке [визначається як "biased in support of a party, group, or cause"](http://thefreedictionary.com/partisan), що і було сутністю поставленого запитання.)

Answer (score -3):

Якщо я правильно розумію, цей сайт присвячений мові, а не мовній політиці. Відповідно, тут розглядаються питання мовні, а не політичні і не соціально-психологічні.

Саме з лінгвістичного, а не з політичного погляду нема жодних проблем з порівнянням можливостей у споріднених мовах і – у випадку, коли усталеного і прямого еквіваленту не існує, – імовірним запозиченням схожого варіанту зі спорідненої мови.

Альтернативою було б залишити мову варитися у власному соку і не давати їй розвиватися, обмежуючи коло тем і питань, які можна нею обговорити, і спектр значень і відтінків, які можна нею виразити. Тобто залишити мову бідною.

Тим більше що Artemix не надавав переклади слова partisan російською. Він узяв варіанти з мови, яка все-таки функціонує подібно до української, і дав найближчі **українські** відповідники російських слів, давши корисну відповідь.

Люди, які не знають російської мови, мають бути вдячні за те, що хтось, хто володіє третьою мовою, запропонував корисні еквіваленти, якими можна скористатися, замість затуляти очі і вуха і волати "Московщина!"

Московщина запозичувала і обертала на свою користь усе, що могла, і тим розвинулася і мовно, і соціально, і політично. Що ширший спектр інструментів, то з більшою кількістю життєвих питань можна впоратися.

Зрештою, сама ідея SE полягає у тому, що тут ми не відсилаємо запитувачів подивитися щось у джерелах. Наприклад, на ELL за пропозицію подивитися у словник відповідь мінусують. Тобто головне те, щоб відповідь була самодостатньою сама по собі. Якщо хтось хоче подивитися джерела і може в них розібратися - чудово. Не усі джерела будуть зрозумілими для запитувачів. Обмеження запитувачів у розумінні сторонніх джерел не повинні слугувати керівним принципом обмеження джерел, якими може користуватися той, хто дає відповідь. Це нормально, коли людина, яка дає відповідь на питання, знає більше, ніж знає запитувач (в нашому випадку - знає ще одну мову, якою можна знайти джерела джерела, в яких можна знайти варіанти, які можна адаптувати до української). Тому-то ця людина, власне, і є тою, хто відповідає на запитання. Якщо хтось ставить запитання на стеку, присвяченому технічним питанням, і відповідь дає посилання на джерела, які запитувач не здатний зрозуміти, тому що не володіє матчастиною, запитувачі не починають кампанію за те, щоб відповіді обмежувалися лише посиланням на ті джерела, що їх вони здатні зрозуміти. Це було б абсурдно. Те саме стосується і цього випадку, якщо тут ідеться про сферу знань, а не про політичні переконання.

Comment: Цікаво, що ті, хто минусує, навіть не намагаються вступити у дискусію - там, заперечити щось по суті чи щось таке. Що тільки додатково доводить, що тут не про лінгвістику і не про принципи функціонування SE, а про психологію.

Comment: перепрошую, це я волаю "московщина"? мій мінус арґументовано йде за те, що вважаю такий тон неприпустимим. я спеціально не став роздувати з цього нічого, а просто поставив питання на меті, щоби всі мали право висказатися. і так, не вказуйте мені, будь ласка, кому я маю бути вдячним. кому маю - вже й так вдячний. політика - це не тільки про людей, які займаються політикою, це просто правила, за якими будуються структури. і я вважаю, що маю право, як активний дописувач цього форуму, на свою думку щодо політики цього форуму. більше вам відповідати не буду, бо не маю емоційних ресурсів на це.

Comment: @P.Vovk Чому взаємодія з моєю відповіддю вимагає від вас витрачати саме емоційні ресурси, а не інтелектуальні? [Чи не є це підтвердженням моєї тези, що тут питання психологічне, а не логічне? Політику, звичайно, можна формувати і на основі психології, але чи доречно це у спільноті, де фокусуються на знаннях?]